# Cannot parse XML from a URL using file_get_contents() in PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

I'm trying to pull information from the following URL (https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=KORL) using PHP, but for some reason I keep getting no information back.

After searching around a bit, I ended up with

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1&stationString=KORL';
  $xml = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
  echo $xml;
?>
```

EDIT: above code is obviously wrong... my updated (and still wrong) code is below.

```
  $url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=KORL';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
 
  $string_data = $xml;
  $xmlstr = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
  $data = (string) $xmlstr->data->METAR->raw_text;
  echo $data;
```

The information I need to get from this is `<raw_text>`.

Any help is greatly appreciated here!

Comment: Why `json_decode()` an XML file? Does `file_get_contents($url)` itself work?

Comment: [Some research reading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: @brombeer so I've tried everything... the example I provided probably wasn't the best as it was a last ditch attempt as I read there are some instances where XML can be read as JSON. My most recent attempt is: `$url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=KORL';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");
 
  $string_data = $xml;
$xmlstr = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$data = (string) $xmlstr->data->METAR->raw_text;
echo $data;`

Comment: Now you're trying to parse it twice. Every time you use a function for the first time you should take a minute to check its manual page and learn what it does exactly. Trying to guess from the name is not always trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `simplexml_load_string()` when you `simplexml_load_file()`. Simply load the XML and access it like you used to:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=KORL';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

$data = (string) $xml->data->METAR->raw_text;
echo $data;
```

will output:

```
KORL 191653Z 08019G24KT 10SM SCT039 BKN085 29/18 A3018 RMK AO2 RAB17E26 SLP222 P0000 T02890183
```

Comment: Oh man... thank you so much! I appreciate you helping me out on this one. Thank you for your explanation too! This is a great help!